# HikariCP is not found when running the jar

Tags: java, hibernate, hikaricp

In a project, we are using Hibernate with HikariCP and it all works fine in Eclipse. But as soon as I generate a jar file (Maven), hikaricp cannot be found anymore. I have turned this in every possible angle, but I cannot figure out what is wrong...

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="starmap" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>net.clanwolf.c3.transfer.pojos.User</class>
        <class>net.clanwolf.c3.transfer.pojos.RolePlayStory</class>
        <class>net.clanwolf.c3.transfer.pojos.RolePlayCharacter</class>
        <class>net.clanwolf.c3.transfer.pojos.RolePlayStoryVar2</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://**.**.**.**:3306/C3?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
            <property name="current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />

            <!-- Hikari connection pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url" value="jdbc:mysql://**.**.**.**:3306/C3?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user" value="**"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="30000" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize" value="250" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit" value="2048" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    ...

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Database persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.33</version> -->
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            <!-- <version>5.0.3.Final</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-hikaricp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        ...

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--@Transactional -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I run this in Eclipse, it is all fine:

> 01:14:05,436  INFO HikariDataSource:70 - HikariPool-1 - Started.

If I run it from the creates jar, it says:

> 01:11:14,631  WARN ConnectionProviderInitiator:256 - HHH000472: Hikari
>   properties were encountered, but the Hikari ConnectionProvider was not
>   found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored.
>   01:11:14,634  WARN connections:71 - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate
>   built-in connection pool (not for production use!) 01:11:14,639  INFO
>   connections:127 - HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]
>   at URL
>   [jdbc:mysql://212.227.253.80:3306/C3?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8]

The file IS in the classpath for sure and I do not see why it would not be found.
Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The file IS in the classpath for sure: if it was, you wouldn't have this error. How do you run your app? Which kind of app is it in the first place? If deployed on a web server, how is it deployed?

Comment: It is a java console application. Actually a server for a game. It connects to the database and provides an accesspoint to local java clients connecting over nadron framework. Maven creates a jar file and I run this from the commandline (java -jar blah.jar). Later, this will be startet on the server by commandline.

Comment: So, how do you run it? Post the command. Post the content of the jar file. Post its manifest. Post the structure of your directories and jar files. If you don't provide any detail, we can't help.

Comment: The difference here is that it works from Eclipse, not from the command line. I think, the structure is not really of help. And besides, the whole thing is pretty big and it would be quite hard to reflect the complete structure here and anything...

Comment: Good luck, then.

Comment: java -jar C3-Server-3.1.2.jar The files in question are contained in that jar file in the right structure. There is the folder org/hibernate/hikaricp/internal with the 3 files contained in the jar that was downloaded by maven. The jar file has hundreds of files and a complex structure. I wouldn't even know how to provide this properly here and it would definitly flood anyone in too much information... So can you think of any info I could give you specifically? I can do that obviously.

Comment: You can check the project here: https://github.com/ClanWolf/C3-Java_Server

Comment: 21500 files in the jar file...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

My project is build with maven-shade. Apparently, if hikariCP is included as class files (not as a jar) in the resulting jar package, it simply does not work. If I provide the CP jars in file system next to my jar and add them to the manifest, they are found.

I have no idea why it would not just use the class files in the package in the first place, but well... They are in that files and they are in the right position, but hikari won't see them.